# How to show every context free language with a certain form?

Tags: context-free-grammar, formal-languages, context-free-language

How can I show that every context-free language can be generated by a grammar in which every production is of the form A → a,A → aB,A → aBC where a is a terminal, and A,B,C are variables?

Comment: This is an interesting question, but since it’s primarily a theoretical question rather than a coding question it might be a better fit at cs.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Look for a proof of "Greibach normal form."